# Inserting a column to a Pandas dataframe using another dataframe as a dictionary

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    item_id     genre
    14441607    COMEDY
    14778825    CHILDREN'S
    10227943    ACTION/ADVENTURE
    10221687    DRAMA
    14778833    ACTION/ADVENTURE
```

I have another dataframe which has sales data for each of the above items for 155 weeks:

```
   item_id      sales
   10221687     1.2
   10221687     0.98
      ""        ""
```

So, 155 such rows for each item. What I am wanting to do is to append the genre for each item into the sales dataframe. The resultant dataframe would look like this:

```
   item_id      sales    genre
   10221687     1.2      DRAMA
   10221687     0.98     DRAMA
      ""        ""         "
```

I have looked at `pd.insert()`, but don't see how to achieve this.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2)` ?

Comment: or `join` assuming item_id is the index.  But either way, start by reading docs on merge and join

Answer (score 0):

considering your sales data is stored in df2, and genre data is stored in df1 the following code will help you merge.

```
 dfMerge = df2.merge(df1, how='left')
```